# Total sum of elements (strings) on an array

Tags: javascript

I am making a program that depending of my 6 characters that I use in  sm4sh, outputs me the characters that helps the other with the large quantity of good matches helping the other character with bad matches, for example, I use Rosalina, she is bad against Mario, but with Ganondorf the match is slightly in my favor, what I want to do right now is the sum of all the elements in the array to check the 54 characters in all the arrays of my 6 characters (to not have imbalanced arrays for the moment).
Thanks.

w//ROSALINA

```
var rosalina_good_matches = ["Ganondorf","King Dedede","Little Mac","Jigglypuff","Duck Hunt","Bowser","Zelda","Dr Mario","Charizard","Donkey Kong","Mr Game and Watch","Robin","Wario","Ness","Palutena","Wii Fit Trainer","Peach","Mewtwo","Samus","Mega Man","ROB","Lucina","Pac-Man","Falco","Toon Link","Yoshi","Marth","Ike","Link","Villager","Kirby","Greninja","Roy","Diddy Kong","Shulk","Luigi","Fox","Lucario","Meta Knight","Olimar","Sonic","Corrin","Sheik"];
var rosalina_even_matches = ["Pit","Dark Pit","Lucas","Captain Falcon","Pikachu","Bayonetta","Cloud"];
var rosalina_bad_matches = ["Mario","Zero Suit Samus","Ryu"];
//Check the sum of 54 characters
for(var i = 0;i < rosalina_good_matches.length;i++){
    console.log(rosalina_good_matches[i]);
}
```

Comment: Can you clarify your question? What exactly you want to do? Question you have asked is not so clear. Also try giving some working code and show us what you have tried so far. @user6343729

Answer (score 0):

To get sum of all array elements (in one string) you should use`.join()` (check https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join)